# What is the time complexity of this problem

Tags: time-complexity

I am in search of validating my solution. I have solved a problem for which i believe the time comlexity is nlogn. Can you please suggest if that is right or wrong, and if wrong why so ? Thanks !

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var originalarray = args;
        //n
        for(int i = 1; i < originalarray.length; i++)
        {
            originalarray[i-1] = i.ToString();
        }

        while(originalarray.Length != 1)//logn
        {
            originalarray = Method(originalarray.Length, originalarray);
        }
    }

    static string[] Method(int input, string[] inputArray)
    {
        var tempArray = new string[input/2];
        for(int i = 1; i <= input/2; i++)//n
        {
            tempArray[i -1] = $"({inputArray[i-1]},{inputArray[input-i]})";
        }
        return tempArray;
    }
```

Comment: 1) `RecursiveMethod` is not recursive since it does not call itself. 2) `for(int i = 1; i <= input/2; i++)//n`: this loop *is* linear time, but the "`n`" is **not** equal to the input length – can you see why, and how this would affect the final result?

Comment: Thanks @meowgoesthedog for your feedback. Yes, you are right, the method is not recursive, and the array length is now dynamic (Made edits after your comment). What I am trying to understand is - in a for loop, i am reducing the iterations by half, does it mean the complexity of that for loop becomes logn instead of N ?